# Extracting embedded text files using RegExp in DotNet

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to use RegExp expression to extract text files stored in a single large field in a database. The field is retrieved into a string variable and the processed by the RegExp DotNet routines.

The files are deliminated like below:

```
%%%%% FILENAME1.TXT %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%

%%%%% FILENAME2.TXT %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%

%%%%% FILENAME2.TXT %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%

%%%%% FILENAME3.RESX %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%

etc. etc
```

The RegExp looks like this:

```
RegExpMatchStr := "^%%%%*[\t ]*([A-Z,a-z,_,-,.,\\,:]*)[\t ]*%%%%*\r+(?s)(.*?)^%%%%*[\t ]*(--END--)[\t ]*%%%%*\r+\s*";
```

However when I test this string in the code (and also on various online sites to test regexp in DotNet) I only seem to get the first of each file extracted.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I am using the MultiLine and IgnoreCase options

```
regex_options := ('RegexOptions'.IgnoreCase as number) + ('RegexOptions'.Multiline as number);

regex_code := NEW NET_OBJECT 'Regex' with RegExpMatchStr as String, regex_options as 'RegexOptions';

single_match := CALL regex_code.Matches with rawcode_text_from_database;
```

I have tried the code on online Regex DotNet sites and it seems to only return one matching set.

EDIT2: Okay.. so the simplification as above now works with the suggested example text above, but not with a more "real" life version of what the code actually looks like:

```
maintenance:
    title:  TEST2;;
    mlmname:  ZMLM_LIB_CSMLM_SAMPLE;;
    arden: version 2.5;;
    version:  0.00;;
    institution:  ;;
    author:  ;;
    specialist:  ;;
    date:  2015-04-10;;
    validation:  testing;;

library:
    purpose:  
    ;;
    explanation:  
    ;;
    keywords:
    ;;
    citations: 
    ;;
knowledge:
    type: data-driven;;
    data:

    standard_libs := MLM 'std_include_libs';
    include standard_libs;

    using "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    using "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    using "System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    using "System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    using "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    using "System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";

    using namespace "System";
    using namespace "System.IO";
    using namespace "System.Text";
    using namespace "System.Data";
    using namespace "System.Text.RegularExpressions";
    using namespace "System.Collections.Generic";

    source_code_MLM := "ZMLM_LIB_CSMLM_SAMPLE";

    (rawcode_text_from_database) := read first { "  SELECT [Logic] FROM [DEVPNL].[dbo].[CV3MLM] WHERE [Name] = " || SQL(source_code_MLM) };

    //RegExpMatchStr := "^%%%%*[\t ]*([A-Z,a-z,_,-,.]*)[\t ]*%%%%*$(?s)(.*?)^%%%%*[\t ]*(END)%%%%*$";
    //RegExpMatchStr := "^%%%%*[\t ]*([A-Z,a-z,_,-,.,\\,:]*)[\t ]*%%%%*\r+(?s)(.*?)^%%%%*[\t ]*(END)[\t ]*%%%%*\r+\s*";
    RexExpMatchStr := "^%%%%*[\t ]*([-A-Za-z_.\\:\d]*)[\t ]*%%%%*(\r?\n)+(?s)(.*?)^%%%%*[\t ]*(END)[\t ]*%%%%*(\r?\n)+\s*";

    regex_code := NEW NET_OBJECT 'Regex' with RegExpMatchStr as String, 'RegexOptions'.Multiline;
    single_match := CALL regex_code.Matches with rawcode_text_from_database;

break;

    //only getting on match

break;

        single_match := CALL single_match.NextMatch;

    endif;


        //code_lines_array := CALL 'Regex'.Split with code_lines_ONLY_from_database[0] as 'String', "\r\n" as 'String';
        //res_lines_array   := CALL 'Regex'.Split with res_lines_ONLY_from_database[0] as 'String', "\r\n" as 'String';


    ;;
    priority: 50
    ;;
    evoke:  
    ;;
    logic:
        conclude true;
    ;;
    action:
    ;;
Urgency: 50;;
end:

maintenance:
    title:  ;;
    mlmname:  ZMLM_LIB_CSMLM_SAMPLE;;
    arden: version 2.5;;
    version:  0.00;;
    institution:  ;;
    author:  ;;
    specialist:  ;;
    date:  2015-04-10;;
    validation:  testing;;

library:
    purpose:  
    ;;
    explanation:  
    ;;
    keywords:
    ;;
    citations: 
    ;;
knowledge:
    type: data-driven;;
    data:
    ;;
    priority: 50
    ;;
    evoke:  
    ;;
    logic:
        conclude true;
    ;;
    action:
    ;;
Urgency: 50;;
end:

%%%%% C:\TEST\SAMPLE.CS %%%%%

using System;

namespace First
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%




%%%%% C:\TEST\SAMPLE.RESX %%%%%

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!-- 
    Microsoft ResX Schema 

    Version 2.0

    The primary goals of this format is to allow a simple XML format 
    that is mostly human readable. The generation and parsing of the 
    various data types are done through the TypeConverter classes 
    associated with the data types.

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `RegexOptions.Multiline` option to match `^` at the beginning of line.

```
string input = 
@"%%%%% FILENAME1.TXT %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%

%%%%% FILENAME2.TXT %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%

%%%%% FILENAME2.TXT %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%

%%%%% FILENAME3.RESX %%%%%

(file content)

%%%%% --END-- %%%%%";
string pattern = @"^%%%%*[\t ]*([-A-Za-z_.\\:\d]*)[\t ]*%%%%*(\r?\n)+(?s)(.*?)^%%%%*[\t ]*(--END--)[\t ]*%%%%*(\r?\n)+\s*";
string[] output = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
                       .OfType<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Value)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: I am using the MultiLine and IgnoreCase options in the Regex configuration. Will add that to above description. I can't show the actual code as it's in a non-standard DotNet language (but calls DotNet objects). As said - I have tried the online testers for DotNet Regex and same happens.

Comment: @dmc2005 What kind of online testers do you try? The following gives 4 matches for me: https://regex101.com/r/cH7kW3/1. Also, please, verify that `Matches` method is invoked in your code (not `Match`). Also, note that I added `\d` into filename regex.

Comment: Actually I first developed the above on regex101 but when the DotNet implementation is different. I then tried - http://regexhero.net/tester/  and http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Okay.. so it looks like my simplification works with your code :)

Comment: I am marking this correct as per the original question, since it does in fact work as per the simplified code. If you could work out why the more accurate file being Regexp'ed doesn't work I will be eternally grateful!